# How can I change div content with JavaScript? No pop up, just Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a div which is going to contain a simple memory card game. The first thing the user is going to see will be a couple of buttons: one for the instructions and another one to start the game.
I would like to make everything happen inside this div, without using popup windows and only using Vanilla JavaScript (even because I am a beginner), so when the user clicks on "instructions" for example the button disappears and the instructions appear (always inside the div), with a "back to menu" button inside. Then, when the user clicks on "start new game", the game starts inside the div

I have found [this idea](https://github.com/lee-joanne/memory-game/tree/master) but there is a pop up which I don't want it to happen, and the div where the initial message and the game happen have different dimensions. I want them to have the same dimensions (obviously they will change because of responsiveness, but this is another thing). I can add my HTML code done so far, but of course is incomplete and makes no sense

```html
<body>
  <!-- Audio files for both win and game over with hide class -->
  <audio id="win-rick" class="hide" controls>
        <source src="assets/audio/you-winnn.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
  <audio id="lose-rick" class="hide" controls>
        <source src="assets/audio/game-overrr.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

  <!-- Main heading -->
  <h1 class="heading">Memento Amiga</h1>

  <!-- Game container -->
  <div id="memory-game">

    <!-- Instructions / Start new game -->
    <div id="magicDiv">
      <button id="instrBtn" type="button">How to play</button>
      <button id="startBtn" type="button">Start new game</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="click-numbers">
    <p id="click-counter-p">Click counter: <span id="click-counter-n">0</span></p>
    <p id="timer-id">Timer: <span id="real-time">60</span></p>
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: There's quite a few mentions of what you want and don't want, but I can't find a question. What is it - exactly - that you want help with? Have you written any JavaScript at all so far? Have you tried to write a [pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) example to list out the various steps of the tasks you want your code to ultimately perform?

Comment: Yes, I have written a pseudo-code example to understand what I need to do. I just know that when a user presses "instructions" only the instructions and the "back to menu" button (yet to create) should be seen, and when a user presses "start new game" the game (which I created, but for the moment I cut away) should appear in the same div area

Comment: So your question is (basically) "how do I change the content of an element depending on which button is pressed?"?

Comment: exactly.  I know i can change the html with the .innerHTML, but I don't think it's the answer because I should change whole parts of it and I have never seen (in my beginner experience) doing something like this

Comment: i think you want to change the style aka the appearance and not the innerHTML aka the content

Comment: Actually I want to change the innerHTML of a div. The problem is that I still haven't understood properly how to work with JavaScript